# Structure List into structure list

Tags: c#, xml, structure

How insert a list structure within another structure list
below our code in C # as we are tried without obtaining a correct result

**Definicion de structuras:**

```
public struct RowField
{
     public string Field;
     public string Value;
}

public struct LinesRow
{
     public string ItemCode;
     public double Quantity;
     public RowField[] UserField;
}
```

**Call structure lines**

```
LinesRow[] Document_Lines,
```

**Obtained result**

```
<LinesRow>
    <ItemCode>string</ItemCode>
    <Quantity>double</Quantity>
    <UserField>
         <RowField xsi:nil="true" />
         <RowField xsi:nil="true" />
     </UserField>
 </LinesRow>
```

**expected result**

```
<LinesRow>
   <ItemCode>string</ItemCode>
   <Quantity>double</Quantity>
   <UserField>
      <RowField>
         <Field>string</Field>
         <Value>string</Value>
      </RowField>
      <RowField>
         <Field>string</Field>
         <Value>string</Value>
      </RowField>
   </UserField>
</LinesRow>
```

Comment: I assume you're serializing this object somehow?